# Java: Exception Handling not working

Tags: java, input, exception

i have a program that I am trying to add exception handling to. The problem is, the exception that i wrote up still exits the program. Basically i offer the user to enter in any int, if they throw me a char, the exception says that they cant do that and lets them enter another int. But it isn't working giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at cit130_hw10_q3.Cit130_hw10_q3.main(Cit130_hw10_q3.java:29)
```

Java Result: 1

Here's some code. Thanks for any help you might offer.

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a series of integers." +
           "When finished enter 999");
   int userInput = 0;
   int inputCount = 0;
   do{
       try{
           System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
           userInput = input.nextInt();
           addToArray(userInput, inputCount);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Only integer values are accepted. Please try again");

       }
       inputCount++;
   }while (userInput != 999);

public static void addToArray(int nextInt , int inputCount){
    integerArray[inputCount] = nextInt;
}
```

Comment: Clear the project, recompile it and retry. Also ensure `Exception` is `java.lang.Exception` not something else

Comment: Your `addToArray` function might throw some more light on the problem you are facing.. Please show that code..

Comment: I guess you mean **while (inputCount != 999)** ?

Comment: @VikasV that would show up in the stack trace though. The stack trace is indicating a problem in main, not in a function.

Comment: Also, note that if `nextInt` throws `InputMismatchException`, it will _not_ advance the scanner. Calling `nextInt` again will just try to re-read the same non-`int` again. You need to invoke `next()` in the `catch` block to advance the token. With that additional tweak, your code works fine on my computer. I think RC has it right.

Comment: @yshavit was correct with his comment. I added the "next()" in the catch statement and now it works fine. The program was getting stuck on that mismatched input

Comment: @yshavit You should post that as an answer

Comment: @nfoggia this still doesn't explain the stack trace. That must've been from some other version of code.

Comment: @MistressDavid That would just be taking credit for RC's answer, which is the real one. :) I just added color commentary on the next bug the OP is likely to face, once they do recompile.

Comment: well in my code that i didn't include here, i had a input.nextInt() in the catch, i removed that and got rid of the trace

Comment: @nfoggia It needs to be just `input.next()`, not `input.nextInt()`. That way it will succeed (and advance the token) no matter what the input is.

Comment: @yshavit yup, thanks for the help =) if you want to put it in answer form id be happy to accept it so others can see what i did wrong. and learn from your correction. haha. thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you forgot to recompile in-between or are running some other version of the code, maybe a different file than this. If you have java.lang.Exception catched like you show, this will ot happen.

Other option is that you have input.nextInt(); somewhere else, too, in a part that you did not paste here. Reconfirm line 29.

Answer (score 0):

Excpetion class is the base class for all exceptions and if you are unsure of exception type you can catch it through java.lang.Excpetion and this works perfectly. In your case please put a break point in the try catch block and then confirm the point where exception is thrown. This will give an insight as why it is not getting catched at the place you mentioned

Comment: That would be better posted as a comment

Comment: Ya you are correct as per stack overflow guidelines this was suppose to be a comment